# Parallel MySQL connections closes temporary table

Tags: php, mysql

I stumbled in the community for my problem but I could not find a solution-maybe it is to specific. The following sequence of functions / operations I am executing in PHP:

1. construct a object of class_1
2. function in class_1 connects to MySQL without a defined link identifier
3. then I create a temporary table [..functions in class_1 do something..]
4. a new function is called which create a object_2 of class_2
5. in object_2 I create a new MySQL connection with the parameter of creating a new link true and link identfier
6. I close the MySQL connection with MySQL_close in object_2 with the link identifier
7. in object_1 the temporary table still not exists / it try to reconnect to MySQL automatically

If I do not create object_2 everything works fine. what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody for help finding a solution. The link identifier solution is as mentioned bit poor for me. at [php.net](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php#52383) is a detailed description of my problem and some hints how to solve:

> Here is how shared links work: 
>      - Each link is a resource. mysql_connect() by default looks for a resource with the same paramaters. If one exists, it will return the
>   existing resource. 
>      - Every assignment of that resource to a variable increases the resource's reference count. 
>      - When the reference is decremented to zero, the underlying TCP/socket connection is closed. 
>        - Every assignment of a variable away from that resource decrements the reference count. (This includes a function level
>   variable going out of scope) 
>        - mysql_close() also decrements the reference count.
>
> Note the last two points: mysql_close() *and* reassignment of a
>   variable decrement the link's reference count.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended.  [From the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html):

> #### "Temporary Tables
>
> You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current connection, and is dropped automatically when the connection is closed. This means that two different connections can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the temporary table is dropped.)"

To avoid this happening, just don't close the connections explicitly.  From the PHP docs for [`mysql_close()`](http://php.net/mysql-close):

> "Using `mysql_close()` isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution. See also [freeing resources](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php#language.types.resource.self-destruct)."

Instead, you should store the connection resources returned by `mysql_connect()` in local variables, so that PHP's garbage collector can automatically close the connection when all references to it have gone out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

How to solve your problem: Add a link identifier in `class_1` as well, otherwise the mysql library would have taken the last one (which you closed).

Comment: well you are right. but the mysql connection of class_1 is used by many different classes, like addons. so a storage might be complicated. if it would close only the last connections it should not have an influence to my temporary table in class_1 ?

Comment: But as you don't share the link of the first connection, after you close in class_2, class_1 uses the wrong link. See [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query)